# Option for function distinct phalcon/mvc/collection

Tags: mongodb, distinct, phalcon

Hello I'm using phalcon Framework.

I need to make a find, normally I would use distinct, but I not found an option.

My class as below :

```
class Calls extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Collection {
public $agent;
public $number;
public $date;
public $status;
}
```

I need to use distinct fields date and number ?

Comment: Try to use native php. $retval = $col->distinct("field_name"); 

http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.distinct.php

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819894/phalcon-how-to-get-distinct-models) will answer your question

Answer (score 1):

you should use query builder:

Basic implementation for later example:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getDI()->getModelsManager()
    ->createBuilder()
    ->addFrom('tableName', 't');
```

Distinct command:

```
$queryBuilder->distinct('t.id');
```

Column thing works too, but not recommended:

```
$queryBuilder->columns('DISTINCT(t.id) AS id')
```