# Phalcon: how to get distinct models?

Tags: php, phalcon

Using [Phalcon Model](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model.html), how can I get distinct rows when get rows using the `find()` method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Using builder:**

Basic implementation for later example:

```
    $queryBuilder = $this->getDI()->getModelsManager()
        ->createBuilder()
        ->addFrom('tableName', 't');
```

Distinct command:

```
    $queryBuilder->distinct('t.id');
```

Column thing works too, but not recommended:

```
    $queryBuilder->columns('DISTINCT(t.id) AS id')
```

Using strictly model:

```
   // we are waiting for it, but may still not be implemented
   TableModel::find(array('distinct' => 'id'))
```

For count:

```
   TableModel::count(array("distinct" => "id"));
```

And less recommended way according to previous answer:

```
   TableModel::find(array('columns' => 'distinct(id)'))
```

And link to imo best [docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/models.html).

Also, there are some issues in [Phalcon 2.0.2](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/9985).

Answer (score 4):

If you have declared some columns you can use:

```
 $result = Word::find(['columns'=>'distinct foo']);
```

Answer (score 0):

In phalcon 3.x it looks like to do a distinct with the Models Manager, the distinct method take a boolean as a parameter. So to do a distinct on a column you should do that:

```html
 $queryBuilder = $this->getDI()->getModelsManager()
        ->createBuilder()
        ->addFrom('tableName', 't')
        ->columns('t.myColumn')
        ->distinct(true)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

Comment: This is false: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/model/query/builder.zep#L299

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, thanks. I just needed to add some parameter to existing code but adding just ->distinct() or with the name of the field didn't work. I work with the 4th version of Phalcon. For anyone else looking 
`->distinct(true)` is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

On some occasions you might wish to use it on model initialization, here is example:

```
/**
 * Class MyModel
 * @property \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple referenceAlias
 * @method int countReferenceAlias
 */
class MyModel extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function initialize(): void
    {
        $this->setSource('my_model');

        $this->hasMany('id', 'ReferenceModel', 'reference_id', [
            'alias' => 'referenceAlias',
            'params' => ['distinct' => 'user_id']
        ]);
    }
}
```

So later on you can make calls this way:

```
print $myModel->countReferenceAlias();
```

or

```
foreach($myModel->referenceAlias() as $userReference){
    print $userReference->user->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define that in your model::**initialize()** method:

```
$this->hasManyToMany(
        'asset_id',
        'NameSpace\AssetsCategory',
        'asset_id',
        'category_id',
        'NameSpace\Category',
        'category_id',
        [
            'alias' => 'SimilarAssets',
            'params' => [
                'group' => 'NameSpace\Category.category_id' // remove duplicate data
            ]
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the group keyword.

```
$result = TableModel::find(array("x_id = $x_id","group"=>"uid"));
```

You can add as many additional arguments to the first section with x_id such as

```
x_id = $x_id AND y_id = 100
```

The second portion is where you specify the field you want to group for TableModel.